# how to fix 500 response code error in Retrofit Android Studio

Tags: android, error-handling, retrofit, android-volley, http-status-code-500

I am facing problem implementing the POST RETROFIT in openrouteservices maps to get round route.
Attached photo below is the error log.[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvH64.jpg)

This is my API Interface

```
Call<Round> getRoundCoordinates(
            /*@Header("Content-Type: application/json") String authHeader ,*/
            @Header("Authorization") String authHeader,
            @Query("coordinates") List<List<Double>> coordinates,
            @Query("length") int length,
            @Query("seed") int seed

    );
```

and 500 Error code is showing. Anyone who can help .Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Error 500 is a server internal error. So either it cannot handle your parameter values or it is totally independent from client-side, the error lays in server code.

Comment: Hmm.. Thanku for your kind help

Answer (score 0):

From the [official document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.1) -

> The **500** **(Internal Server Error)** status code indicates that the server
> encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling
> the request.

So you need to discuss with you backend team about it because it is an error occurred in the server, not your app (Client-side)

Comment: what if i cannot discuss with them. I am using openrouteservices to get round maps

Comment: Please you can check it - https://ask.openrouteservice.org/t/solved-internal-server-error-500-unable-to-build-isochrone-map/1177/6